# In C# how could I find all possible Cliques of a graph?

Tags: c#, computer-science, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Assume I have a graph with adjacent matrix n*n, how can I using c# to find all possible cliques in the graph, remember a clique means all node are connected to each other, if we have 3 nodes only, then to be a clique then 1 must connect with 2 and 2 must connect with 3 and 1 must connect with 3.

Comment: Please note that So is supposed to be a QA website for questions that have a long-term value. Also, questions need to show what the poster has already tried. Please post your pseudo-code and the C# code that you have already tried.

Comment: You never had any "rep" so ts not like you lost marks, suggest you take this as a hint your questions don't show research effort, are unclear or not useful. Read [Jon Skeets article Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and check out the comments I post in some of your other questions to help you ask better questions in order to get better answers. To improve this question as @user247077 mentions add code showing us what you've tried.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: The link to Jon Skeets article is broken. Do you have a working one?

Comment: The tinyurl is broken, but its easy enough to google: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Yeah I used Google and found it but I think a posted link should work. It's clear that a link might be broken if you find it years after it was posted but your post is only 30 mins old. Thx for the new link.

Comment: Apply dijkstr'a algorithm.  Posted solution many times before.  Here is the code.

Comment: I think this question should be closed, but I don't have voting rights. If anyone else agrees, could they try please?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code.  I have two different versions below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this one uses strings as node names
            Dijkstra1.Program.Dijkstra();
            //this one uses integers as node names
            Dijkstra2.Program.Dijkstra();
        }
    }
}
namespace Dijkstra1
{
    class Program
    {
        //A connected to B
        //B connected to A, C , D
        //C connected to B, D
        //D connected to B, C , E
        //E connected to D.
        static List<List<String>> input1 = new List<List<string>>{
               new List<String>() {"A","0","1","0","0","0"},
               new List<String>() {"B","1","0","1","1","0"},
               new List<String>() {"C","0","1","0","1","0"},
               new List<String>() {"D","0","1","1","0","1"},
               new List<String>() {"E","0","0","0","1","0"}
            };
        //A  |   0 1 2 2 3  |
        //B  |   1      0      1      1      2       |
        //C  |   2      1      0      1      2       | 
        //D  |   2      1      1      0      1       |
        //E  |   3      2      2      1      0       |
        static List<List<String>> input2 = new List<List<string>>{
               new List<String>() {"A","0","1","2","2","3"},
               new List<String>() {"B","1","0","1","1","2"},
               new List<String>() {"C","2","1","0","1","2"},
               new List<String>() {"D","2","1","1","0","1"},
               new List<String>() {"E","3","2","2","1","0"}
            };
        static public void Dijkstra()
        {
            CGraph cGraph;
            cGraph = new CGraph(input1);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------Input 1 -------------");
            cGraph.PrintGraph();
            cGraph = new CGraph(input2);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------Input 2 -------------");
            cGraph.PrintGraph();
        }
        class CGraph
        {
            List<Node> graph = new List<Node>();
            public CGraph(List<List<String>> input)
            {
                foreach (List<string> inputRow in input)
                {
                    Node newNode = new Node();
                    newNode.name = inputRow[0];
                    newNode.distanceDict = new Dictionary<string, Path>();
                    newNode.visited = false;
                    newNode.neighbors = new List<Neighbor>();
                    //for (int index = 1; index < inputRow.Count; index++)
                    //{
                    //    //skip diagnol values so you don't count a nodes distance to itself.
                    //    //node count start at zero
                    //    // index you have to skip the node name
                    //    //so you have to subtract one from the index
                    //    if ((index - 1) != nodeCount)
                    //    {
                    //        string nodeName = input[index - 1][0];
                    //        int distance = int.Parse(inputRow[index]);
                    //        newNode.distanceDict.Add(nodeName, new List<string>() { nodeName });
                    //    } 
                    //}
                    graph.Add(newNode);
                }
                //initialize neighbors using predefined dictionary
                for (int nodeCount = 0; nodeCount < graph.Count; nodeCount++)
                {
                    for (int neighborCount = 0; neighborCount < graph.Count; neighborCount++)
                    {
                        //add one to neighbor count to skip Node name in index one
                        if (input[nodeCount][neighborCount + 1] != "0")
                        {
                            Neighbor newNeightbor = new Neighbor();
                            newNeightbor.node = graph[neighborCount];
                            newNeightbor.distance = int.Parse(input[nodeCount][neighborCount + 1]);
                            graph[nodeCount].neighbors.Add(newNeightbor);
                            Path path = new Path();
                            path.nodeNames = new List<string>() { input[neighborCount][0] };
                            //add one to neighbor count to skip Node name in index one
                            path.totalDistance = int.Parse(input[nodeCount][neighborCount + 1]);
                            graph[nodeCount].distanceDict.Add(input[neighborCount][0], path);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (Node node in graph)
                {
                    foreach (Node nodex in graph)
                    {
                        node.visited = false;
                    }
                    TransverNode(node);
                }
            }
            public class Neighbor
            {
                public Node node { get; set; }
                public int distance { get; set; }
            }
            public class Path
            {
                public List<string> nodeNames { get; set; }
                public int totalDistance { get; set; }
            }
            public class Node
            {
                public string name { get; set; }
                public Dictionary<string, Path> distanceDict { get; set; }
                public Boolean visited { get; set; }
                public List<Neighbor> neighbors { get; set; }
            }
            static void TransverNode(Node node)
            {
                if (!node.visited)
                {
                    node.visited = true;
                    foreach (Neighbor neighbor in node.neighbors)
                    {
                        TransverNode(neighbor.node);
                        string neighborName = neighbor.node.name;
                        int neighborDistance = neighbor.distance;
                        //compair neighbors dictionary with current dictionary
                        //update current dictionary as required
                        foreach (string key in neighbor.node.distanceDict.Keys)
                        {
                            if (key != node.name)
                            {
                                int neighborKeyDistance = neighbor.node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance;
                                if (node.distanceDict.ContainsKey(key))
                                {
                                    int currentDistance = node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance;
                                    if (neighborKeyDistance + neighborDistance < currentDistance)
                                    {
                                        List<string> nodeList = new List<string>();
                                        nodeList.AddRange(neighbor.node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames);
                                        nodeList.Insert(0, neighbor.node.name);
                                        node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames = nodeList;
                                        node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance = neighborKeyDistance + neighborDistance;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    List<string> nodeList = new List<string>();
                                    nodeList.AddRange(neighbor.node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames);
                                    nodeList.Insert(0, neighbor.node.name);
                                    Path path = new Path();
                                    path.nodeNames = nodeList;
                                    path.totalDistance = neighbor.distance + neighborKeyDistance;
                                    node.distanceDict.Add(key, path);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            public void PrintGraph()
            {
                foreach (Node node in graph)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Node : {0}", node.name);
                    foreach (string key in node.distanceDict.Keys.OrderBy(x => x))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" Distance to node {0} = {1}, Path : {2}", key, node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance, string.Join(",", node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames.ToArray()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
namespace Dijkstra2
{
    class Program
    {
         //0---1---2---3
         //     |
         //    4
         //     |
         //    5---6---7
         //     \  /
         //      8
         //      |
         //      9 

        static List<List<int>> input1 = new List<List<int>>
         {       // 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
                new List<int>() {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new List<int>() {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new List<int>() {2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new List<int>() {3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new List<int>() {4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new List<int>() {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                new List<int>() {6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
                new List<int>() {7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                new List<int>() {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                new List<int>() {9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         }; 

        static public void Dijkstra()
        {
            CGraph cGraph;
            cGraph = new CGraph(input1);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------Input 1 -------------");
            cGraph.PrintGraph();
        }
        class CGraph
        {
            List<Node> graph = new List<Node>();
            public CGraph(List<List<int>> input)
            {
                foreach (List<int> inputRow in input)
                {
                    Node newNode = new Node();
                    newNode.name = inputRow[0];
                    newNode.distanceDict = new Dictionary<int, Path>();
                    newNode.visited = false;
                    newNode.neighbors = new List<Neighbor>();
                    //for (int index = 1; index < inputRow.Count; index++)
                    //{
                    //    //skip diagnol values so you don't count a nodes distance to itself.
                    //    //node count start at zero
                    //    // index you have to skip the node name
                    //    //so you have to subtract one from the index
                    //    if ((index - 1) != nodeCount)
                    //    {
                    //        string nodeName = input[index - 1][0];
                    //        int distance = int.Parse(inputRow[index]);
                    //        newNode.distanceDict.Add(nodeName, new List<string>() { nodeName });
                    //    } 
                    //}
                    graph.Add(newNode);
                }
                //initialize neighbors using predefined dictionary
                for (int nodeCount = 0; nodeCount < graph.Count; nodeCount++)
                {
                    for (int neighborCount = 0; neighborCount < graph.Count; neighborCount++)
                    {
                        //add one to neighbor count to skip Node name in index one
                        if (input[nodeCount][neighborCount + 1] != 0)
                        {
                            Neighbor newNeightbor = new Neighbor();
                            newNeightbor.node = graph[neighborCount];
                            newNeightbor.distance = input[nodeCount][neighborCount + 1];
                            graph[nodeCount].neighbors.Add(newNeightbor);
                            Path path = new Path();
                            path.nodeNames = new List<int>() { input[neighborCount][0] };
                            //add one to neighbor count to skip Node name in index one
                            path.totalDistance = input[nodeCount][neighborCount + 1];
                            graph[nodeCount].distanceDict.Add(input[neighborCount][0], path);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (Node node in graph)
                {
                    foreach (Node nodex in graph)
                    {
                        node.visited = false;
                    }
                    TransverNode(node);
                }
            }
            public class Neighbor
            {
                public Node node { get; set; }
                public int distance { get; set; }
            }
            public class Path
            {
                public List<int> nodeNames { get; set; }
                public int totalDistance { get; set; }
            }
            public class Node
            {
                public int name { get; set; }
                public Dictionary<int, Path> distanceDict { get; set; }
                public Boolean visited { get; set; }
                public List<Neighbor> neighbors { get; set; }
            }
            static void TransverNode(Node node)
            {
                if (!node.visited)
                {
                    node.visited = true;
                    foreach (Neighbor neighbor in node.neighbors)
                    {
                        TransverNode(neighbor.node);
                        int neighborName = neighbor.node.name;
                        int neighborDistance = neighbor.distance;
                        //compair neighbors dictionary with current dictionary
                        //update current dictionary as required
                        foreach (int key in neighbor.node.distanceDict.Keys)
                        {
                            if (key != node.name)
                            {
                                int neighborKeyDistance = neighbor.node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance;
                                if (node.distanceDict.ContainsKey(key))
                                {
                                    int currentDistance = node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance;
                                    if (neighborKeyDistance + neighborDistance < currentDistance)
                                    {
                                        List<int> nodeList = new List<int>();
                                        nodeList.AddRange(neighbor.node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames);
                                        nodeList.Insert(0, neighbor.node.name);
                                        node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames = nodeList;
                                        node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance = neighborKeyDistance + neighborDistance;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    List<int> nodeList = new List<int>();
                                    nodeList.AddRange(neighbor.node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames);
                                    nodeList.Insert(0, neighbor.node.name);
                                    Path path = new Path();
                                    path.nodeNames = nodeList;
                                    path.totalDistance = neighbor.distance + neighborKeyDistance;
                                    node.distanceDict.Add(key, path);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            public void PrintGraph()
            {
                foreach (Node node in graph)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Node : {0}", node.name);
                    foreach (int key in node.distanceDict.Keys.OrderBy(x => x))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" Distance to node {0} = {1}, Path : {2}", key, node.distanceDict[key].totalDistance, string.Join(",", node.distanceDict[key].nodeNames.ToArray()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

​
```

Comment: Error 1 'Dijkstra1.Program' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: What input are you using.  I have two versions.  One accepts string as node name and the other accepts integers as node names.